# Compare properties of two objects fast c#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, comparison

I have two objects of same type with different values:

```
    public class Itemi
    {
    public Itemi()
    {

    }

    public int Prop1Min { get; set; }
    public int Prop1Max { get; set; }

    public int Prop2Min { get; set; }
    public int Prop2Max { get; set; }

    public int Prop3Min { get; set; }
    public int Prop3Max { get; set; }
    ...................................
    public int Prop25Min { get; set; }
    public int Prop25Max { get; set; }

    }
```

Now I instantiate two objects of this type and add some values to their properties.

```
Itemi myItem1 = new Itemi();

myItem1.Prop1Min = 1;
myItem1.Prop1Max = 4;

myItem1.Prop2Min = 2;
myItem1.Prop2Max = 4;

myItem1.Prop3Min = -1;
myItem1.Prop3Max = 5;

.............................

myItem1.Prop25Min = 1;
myItem1.Prop25Max = 5;

Itemi myItem2 = new Itemi();

myItem2.Prop1Min = 1;
myItem2.Prop1Max = 5;

myItem2.Prop2Min = -10;
myItem2.Prop2Max = 3;

myItem2.Prop3Min = 0;
myItem2.Prop3Max = 2;

................................

myItem2.Prop25Min = 3;
myItem2.Prop25Max = 6;
```

What is the best and fastest way to do this comparison:

- take each properties from myItem1 and check if values from Prop1-25 Min and Max are within the range values of myItem2 Prop1-25 Min and Max

Example:

```
   myItem1.Prop1Min = 1
   myItem1.Prop1Max = 4

   myItem2.Prop1Min = 1
   myItem2.Prop1Max = 5
```

this is True because mtItem1 Prop1 min and max are within the range of myItem2 min and max.

the condition should be AND in between all properties so in the end after we check all 25 properties if all of them are within the range of the second object we return true.

Is there a fast way to do this using Linq or other algorithm except the traditional if-else?

Comment: Do you *really* need 50 separate properties, rather than 2 properties, each of which is a collection?

Comment: Also it's nice to create *Range* object to hold Min and Max values

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @Jon - I think some good old fashion programmer wisdom needs to be applied.

Comment: @DavidDury: You've got Prop1Min, Prop1Max, Prop2Min, Prop2Max etc. If you have Minima and Maxima, each of which had 25 values, it would be easier to deal with.

Comment: @DavidDury Create two collections, one for all of the min values, and one for all of the max values, and fill each collection with 25 objects.  Better yet, create a type that holds onto two ints, a min and a max, and make a collection of 25 of those types.

Comment: You problem isn't performace.

Comment: If by "fast" you mean "fast to code", then you should keep in mind that the way these properties are laid out actively works against that.

Comment: These properties are actual values the users will enter and if let's say property 15 is not within the range I will have to inform user about that property 15 that is not in the range. How do I keep track of properties name if I implement the scenario you suggest?

Comment: Dumb me ... of course you can add another field called Property_name ...

Comment: @DavidDury OMG are you planning to deploy this to end users?

Comment: Daivd I think what everyone is saying is that you should not add 15 some odd properties where you could accomplish the same thing using a List<Range> which creating a class with the 2 properties Min/Max would be the more optimal way to do things .. think of it this way.. `who in coding wants to duplicate the same functionality 50 times` ...

Comment: @HighCore: yep, that's what they need ...

Comment: @DavidDury if this is your "data model", I can only image what the rest of the application code looks like...

Answer (score 3):

I would refactor the properties to be more along the lines of:

```
public class Item
{
    public List<Range> Ranges { get; set; }
}

public class Range
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
}
```

Then your comparison method could be:

```
if (myItem1.Ranges.Count != myItem2.Ranges.Count)
{
    return false;
}

for (int i = 0; i < myItem1.Ranges.Count; i++)
{
    if (myItem1.Ranges[i].Min < myItem2.Ranges[i].Min ||
        myItem1.Ranges[i].Max > myItem2.Ranges[i].Max)
    {
        return false;
    }
}        
return true;
```

Otherwise you will have to use Reflection, which is anything but fast.

Comment: @Servy: I added a LINQ solution :)

Comment: @Servy: LINQ is a great tool. Like with any tool, it's important to know when (and when not) to use it. You wouldn't use a hammer to drive a screw.

Comment: @Ginosaji So you think LINQ is not an appropriate tool to use in solving this problem?  I strongly disagree. Your `for` loop can be easily refactored to a call to `Zip` and `All` (as demonstrated by Sebastian's answer), which will make it shorter and (arguably) clearer.  It would not, in any way, be an inappropriate tool for the job.  If you're not aware of the capabilities of LINQ and how to use it, you might consider not answering questions specifically asking how to code a solution in LINQ (which is the case here).

Comment: @Servy: As demonstrated in Sebastian's answer, I would indeed say that LINQ only serves to obscure the intent in this situation. I'm well aware of the capabilities of LINQ, and I would advise against using LINQ only for the sake of using LINQ. Also, despite the tag, nothing in the phrasing of this question precludes non-LINQ solutions.

Comment: @Ginosaji It seems you missed the part of the question that actually does specifically preclude this solution:  `"Is there a fast way to do this using Linq or other algorithm except the traditional if-else?"`

Comment: @Servy: I believe you misinterpreted that quote. In fact, that's the exact quote I would post to prove that it doesn't preclude this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Linq is using standart statements like if...then, for each and other, there is no magic :)

If the final goal only to compare, without needing to say, which properties are not in the range, then you not need to check them all, on the first unequals you can end checking.

Because you have so much properties, you must think about saving it in Dictionary, or List, for example. Or to use dynamic properties ([ITypedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx)), if it will use for binding.

Answer (score 0):

You really should do something like Ginosaji proposed.

But if you want to go with your current data model, here is how I would solve it. Happy typing. :)

```
public static bool RangeIsContained(int outerMin, int outerMax, int innerMin, int innerMax)
{
    return (outerMin <= innerMin && outerMax >= innerMax);
}

public bool IsContained(Itemi outer, Itemi inner)
{
    return RangeIsContained(outer.Prop1Min, outer.Prop1Max, inner.Prop1Min, inner.Prop1Max)
        && RangeIsContained(outer.Prop2Min, outer.Prop2Max, inner.Prop2Min, inner.Prop2Max)
        // ...
        && RangeIsContained(outer.Prop25Min, outer.Prop25Max, inner.Prop25Min, inner.Prop25Max);
}
```

With your data model this is basically the only way to go except for reflection (slow!). LINQ cannot help you because your data is not enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is a LINQ solution (but it's less performant and less readable than Ginosaji's solution!)

```
public class Range
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    public static bool IsContained(Range super, Range sub)
    {
        return super.Min <= sub.Min
            && super.Max >= sub.Max;
    }
}

public class Itemi
{
    public Itemi()
    {
        properties = new Range[25];
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
        {
            properties[i] = new Range();
        }
    }

    private Range[] properties;

    public IEnumerable<Range> Properties { get { return properties; } }

    public static bool IsContained(Itemi super, Itemi sub)
    {
        return super.properties
            .Zip(sub.properties, (first, second) => Tuple.Create(first, second))
            .All((entry) => Range.IsContained(entry.Item1, entry.Item2));
    }

    public Range Prop1 
    { 
        get { return properties[0]; }
        set { properties[0] = value; }
    }

    public Range Prop2
    {
        get { return properties[1]; }
        set { properties[1] = value; }
    }

    // ...
}
```